# Difference between SPFile and FolderItem (Logical Error in code)

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

```
 private void bFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode currentNode = trvContent.SelectedNode;
        SPObjectData objectData = (SPObjectData)currentNode.Tag;
        using (SPWeb TopLevelWeb = objectData.Web)
        {
            dwnEachWeb(TopLevelWeb);
        }
    }

    private void dwnEachWeb(SPWeb TopLevelWeb)
    {
        if (TopLevelWeb.Webs.Count == 0)
        {
            dwnEachList(TopLevelWeb);
        }
        foreach (SPWeb ChildWeb in TopLevelWeb.Webs)
        {
            dwnEachWeb(ChildWeb);
            ChildWeb.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void dwnEachList(SPWeb oWeb)
    {
        if (oWeb.Lists.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (SPList oList in oWeb.Lists)
            {
                if (oList.ItemCount != 0 && oList.Title != "Master Page Gallery")
                {
                    dwnEachFolder(oList.RootFolder);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void dwnEachFolder(SPFolder oFolder)
    {
        if (oFolder.SubFolders.Count == 0)
        {
            dwnEachFile(oFolder);
        }
        foreach(SPFolder SubFolder in oFolder.SubFolders)
        {
            dwnEachFolder(SubFolder);
        }
    }

    private void dwnEachFile(SPFolder oFolder)
    {
        if (oFolder.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach(SPFile ofile in oFolder.Files)
            {
                if (CreateDirectoryStructure(tbDirectory.Text, ofile.Url))
                {
                    var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(tbDirectory.Text, ofile.Url);
                    byte[] binFile = ofile.OpenBinary();
                    System.IO.FileStream fstream = System.IO.File.Create(filepath);
                    fstream.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
                    fstream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //creating directory        
    private bool CreateDirectoryStructure(string baseFolder, string filepath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(baseFolder)) return false;

        var paths = filepath.Split('/');

        for (var i = 0; i < paths.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            baseFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseFolder, paths[i]);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(baseFolder);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Code has a logical problem , tried to debug, but when it comes to code line

```
foreach(SPFile ofile in oFolder.Files)
```

in method dwnEachFile, it simply comes out of method without stating any problem and not creating any directory at all. however if I hover ova SPFile it says,

> a file in sharepoint website that can be a web part page, an item in a
>   document library or a file in a folder.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on the first line of the CreateDirectoryStructure method. Does it get hit?

Comment: Nope, i already mentioned that in the quesiton.

Comment: What is the value of oFolder.Files.Count in dwnEachFile?

Comment: it keeps changing , last time it was 2 and I tried to debugged the code and problem is am talking a folder from list and trying to get its files, which for some reason spFile isn;t liking. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem with code is I am looking for each file in a folder and its sub folder of a web, but I Was suppose to Look into each list and its sub list of a web and then each document library folder in each of the list.

This MSDN link explains it all

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spdocumentlibrary.aspx)